# how to float an image on top of a div

Tags: html, css

I have something as follow.

http://jsfiddle.net/gJX5e/2/

I want to see my image inside my `div` be able to show the whole image. (currently it's cut off because of the parent container's height.) I can't change parent container's height and I want to see the image that float on top of the parent container. (so I use absolute position). However, it doesn't work. can anyone help me about it? Thanks.

desire result

```
 ----------------------------
|     -----------
|    |           |
|    |     img1  |
 ---              -------------------
     |           |
      -----------
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your `overflow` to `visible` on `#container`.

Comment: I can't. I need it to be hiddle. :( +1 though

Answer (score 1):

```
#container {
     overflow: visible;
}

#slide-list {
     overflow: visible;
}
```

Or just delete altogether the rule, since the [default for `overflow` is, indeed, `visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

<kbd>[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJX5e/4/)</kbd>

Comment: I can't. I need it to be hiddle. :( +1 though

Comment: If you need that to be hidden you have no option but making your image not a child of your element. Perhaps use another containing `div` so that you can then absolute position your image inside it.